# Meteor method returns null on client, same method run on client returns proper value

Tags: javascript, meteor

I got the intended behavior, but Im confused why...

I have this Meteor method, which returns the value of a document key; the log statement proves such:

```
findUserEmail: function(user_id){
    var user = Meteor.users.find({_id: user_id}).fetch();
    console.log(user[0].emails[0].address);
    return user[0].emails[0].address;
}
```

But when I call it on the client, the `shared_user_email` field is `null`:

`shared_user_email: Meteor.call('findUserEmail', $(ev.target).find('[name=shared_user]').val())`

BUT, when I simulate calling the Meteor method by mimicking the server query on client, it returns the value that the Meteor method above logs:

`shared_user_email: Meteor.users.find({_id: $(ev.target).find('[name=shared_user]').val()}).fetch()[0].emails[0].address`

What is lost in translation when the client tries calling the server method?

**EDIT**

What happens when I use a Meteor method to insert a document into my collection, whose field relies on a Meteor method?  I keep getting `undefined` for my `shared_user_email` field here:

```
var newList = {
        title: $(ev.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
        description: $(ev.target).find('[name=description]').val(),
        dateCreated: today.toDateString(),
        owner: Meteor.userId(),
        owner_email: Meteor.users.find({_id: Meteor.userId()}).fetch()[0].emails[0].address,
        shared_user: $(ev.target).find('[name=shared_user]').val(),
        shared_user_email: Meteor.call('find_shared_user_email', 
            $(ev.target).find('[name=shared_user]').val(),
             function(err, user_email){
                return user_email;
            })
    }

    Meteor.call('addList', newList, function(err, list){
        return list;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client, you need to invoke the callback function of `Meteor.call()` to retrieve the value from your method.

From the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call):

> On the client, if you do not pass a callback and you are not inside a
>   stub, call will return undefined, and you will have no way to get the
>   return value of the method. That is because the client doesn't have
>   fibers, so there is not actually any way it can block on the remote
>   execution of a method.

It should work as follows:

```
Meteor.call(
  'findUserEmail',
  user_id,
  function(error, result){
    // 'result' here is email address from method
  }
);
```

Comment: im confused on the intuition behind a fiber, if you can spare a minute

Comment: Here is a good introduction on Fibers in Meteor and Node from one of Meteor's best open source contributors: https://meteorhacks.com/fibers-eventloop-and-meteor.html. The basic idea re: your question is that when you invoke Meteor.call() from the client, you need to wait for the result to come back. But that is not always immediate, and the rest of your code will continue to be executed. So you need to invoke the callback function to wait for the result.

Comment: You could get this to work by first running Meteor.call('find_shared_user_email'), setting the result to a variable, and if the variable is defined, setting newList.sharedUserEmail to that variable. However there is a better way to be doing all of this. You should retrieve the email of the shared user not by using Meteor.call() but by using the publish/subscribe architecture.

Comment: To do that, you could set a Session property to the user_id that is to be shared, and then use Tracker.autorun() to subscribe to the shared_user. In the publication for the shared user, you can just publish the emails field for the user if that is all you will need.

Comment: Lastly, note that there is an easier way to query for users. Instead of Meteor.users.find({_id: Meteor.userId()}).fetch()[0].emails[0].address, you can use Meteor.user().emails[0].address if it is the current logged in user, or in the case of the shared user, Users.findOne(user_id).emails[0].address

Comment: what is the benefit of using pubsub/Meteor methods as opposed to just querying the collection on the client?

Comment: Publications and subscriptions are how the data reaches the client side collection in the first place. If you know that the email of the shared user is already published to a client collection (for example, if you have a pre-existing publication for all user emails), you can skip setting up a new pub/sub for just that one email. Otherwise you'd need a new sub for it. Method calls, by contrast, are best reserved for actions like inserting and updating to the db, calling remote apis, etc. I recommend 1. the 'Discover Meteor' book and 2. the Meteor docs for coverage of these broader topics.

Answer (score 1):

The code above doesn't work because you didn't get an asynchronous response from the first server call yet:

```
var newList = {
    /* some code */
    shared_user_email: Meteor.call('find_shared_user_email', 
        $(ev.target).find('[name=shared_user]').val(),
         function(err, user_email){
            /* this code is executing asynchronous */
            return user_email;
        })
}

/* the following call won't wait for the previous server call's completion */
Meteor.call('addList', newList, function(err, list){
    return list;
});
```

Instead you have to make the second call only when you know for sure that the first call is finished, for example:

```
var newList = {
    /* some code */
};

Meteor.call('find_shared_user_email', 
    $(ev.target).find('[name=shared_user]').val(),
     function(err, user_email){
        newList.shared_user_email = user_email;
        Meteor.call('addList', newList, function(err, list){
            /* other code to handle the added list */
        });
    })
}
```